# Reverse Proxy periodically stops working till restart

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

We have an Ubuntu Server running as a Reverse Proxy (Apache) for all our Servers, which are hosted in Azure.

Every month or so (not regular), the Proxy server stops processing requests, and all of our sites stop communicating with the outside world.

Restarting the Server immediately fixes the issue.

We have checked

- CPU
- Memory (RAM)
- Network volume

And none of these seem to be contributing to these outages.

What should a Sysadmin would check that could be causing the Proxy to stop functioning, before restarting?

Comment: *What should a Sysadmin would check* - log files for a start. Anticipating the question "which log files" - all of them